# Is it possible to create sum function from reduce and curry without inline functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sum, reduce

I want to create function sum out of curry and reduce if I have standard functions `apply` and `call`:

My try:

```js
// those are init functions:

function type(label, arg, type) {
  // some type checking so you know which function
  // throw exception and why
  var arg_type;
  if (arg instanceof Array) {
     arg_type = 'array';
  } else if (arg === null) {
     arg_type = 'null';
  } else {
     arg_type = typeof arg;
  }
  if (arg_type !== type) {
    throw new Error(`${label}: Expecting ${type} got ${arg_type}`);
  }
}


function curry(fn, ...init_args) {
    type('curry', fn, 'function');
    var len = fn.length;
    return function() {
        var args = init_args.slice();
        function call(...more_args) {
            args = args.concat(more_args);
            //console.log({fn, len, args});
            if (args.length >= len) {
                return fn.apply(this, args);
            } else {
                return call;
            }
        }
        return call.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
function reduce(fn, init, ...lists) {
    if (lists.some(l => !l.length)) {
        return init;
    }
    type('reduce', fn, 'function');
    lists.forEach(a => type('reduce', a, 'array'));
    const head = lists.map(l => l[0]);
    const rest = lists.map(l => l.slice(1));
    return reduce(fn, fn(...head, init), ...rest);
}
function apply(fn, args) {
   type('apply', fn, 'function');
   type('apply', args, 'array');
   return fn.apply(null, args);
}
function call(fn, ...args) {
    type('call', fn, 'function');
    return fn.call(null, ...args);
}
var add = (a, b) => a + b;

// and this only using those without new inline function
var sum = curry(call, curry(reduce, add));
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
var sum = curry(apply, curry(reduce, add));
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Is it possible to create sum function with: curry, apply, reduce and/or call? If not is it possible to add some generic known function that will allow to create sum without inline functions (this include arrow functions)?

I can create sum functions like this:

```
var sum = (...args) => reduce(add, 0, args);
```

so it seems what I need is function that get list of arguments and call function as array.

```
function caller(fn, ...args) {
   return fn.call(null, args);
}
var sum = curry(caller, curry(reduce, add, 0));
console.log(curry(reduce, add, 0)([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));

function spread(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        return call(fn, args);
    };
}

var sum = spread(curry(reduce, add, 0));
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Does functions like `caller` and `spread` have some common name? Or is there a better way to create sum function, with those requirement? I can also use `pipe` or `compose` functions because they are also common, not sure if you can use them to create sum.

So basically my question is this, is possible to create sum function using  any known function in functional libraries without any inline functions? Builtin functions like `bind` are also allowed.

**This can be generalized to create a function from function two arguments that can be called with any arguments and it reduce on each argument without using inline function.**

I want to know this because I want to know more about function programming.

Comment: So, I take it you never want to define mathematical addition as a separate function, just re-use existing ones? It's a bit of an odd requirement. I'm not sure it is possible - mathematical operations are wholly different to working other functions (or their arguments). I guess at best you might trick it using some sort of array join that uses `+` under the hood but that would be very implementation dependant.

Comment: @VLAZ this is one exception add as function, I need this mainly for my lisp interpreter where I have + builtin function, but it's easier to ask with JavaScript (that's why I have `const add = (a, b) => a + b` in question. In my lisp I have `+` function that work like `sum` but I want to use it like it accept only two arguments just to know better function programming).

Comment: Your `curry` function is mixing things up. Either it should take initial arguments, and be called `partiallyApply`, or it should not take them and simply curry a function.

Comment: `spread` and `caller` have no place in functional programming because they create variadic functions, which are not easy to type and do not work well together with currying. Why not simple have your `sum` function take a single iterable (array, list, ...) argument?

Comment: @Bergi Currying and partial application do not have to be mutually exclusive. Here's an [implementation](https://github.com/aaditmshah/aang/blob/master/src/curry.js) which marries the two. I like to call this function `equicurry` (derived from [equirecursive types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type#Equirecursive_types)) because it can both auto `curry` and auto `uncurry` higher order functions, thereby blurring the line between the two.

Comment: However, I do agree that the OPs problem is because of variadic arguments. What's wrong with writing `sum([1, 2, 3, 4])`? You can define `const sum = curry(reduce, add, 0);`.

Comment: @AaditMShah it's nothing wrong, but I wanted to know if it's possible to create `const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);` using functional style and function `const add = (a, b) => a + b;` (and no other inline functions) just to learn more about this technics. But if there is problem with variadic functions in Functional programming, then that's explanation is fine with me.

Comment: Yeah, variadic arguments aren't functional. At least not in the sense that you're using them. Variadic arguments make it difficult to compose functions and are generally a pain. You'd be better off using arrays in place of variadic arguments. All you have to do is type in two extra characters, `[` and `]`.

Comment: That being said, you can have principled variadic arguments in functional programming using a form of dependent typing. For example, `printf("%d + %d = %d", 2, 3, 5)` can be implemented using functional programming concepts. The difference is that in this case we know that there are going to be exactly 3 variadic arguments. Hence, we can assign a dependent type to the `printf` function.

Comment: Another example for Bergi, is [Racket's curry](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by inline functions.
But:

```
function ad = (a, b) => a + b;

function sum (...args) {
  return args.reduce(add, 0);
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

EDIT: Didn't understand the original question, here is the answer

```
// From lodash, is named differently in other FP libraries
const partialRight = (func, ...boundArgs) =>  (...remainingArgs) => 
func(...remainingArgs, ...boundArgs);

// From Lodash 
const rest = (fn) => (...args) => fn(args);

// From any FP library
const reduce = function(iterable, reduceFn, accumulator){
  for(let i of iterable){
    accumulator = reduceFn(accumulator, i)
  }
  return accumulator
}

const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const sum = rest(partialRight(reduce, add, 0));

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: This is old, did you actually read the question, it have your code `var sum = (...args) => reduce(add, 0, args);` Here I'm asking how to create using sum using curry + reduce. without using functions only partial application, which if you read the comments is not possible.

Comment: @jcubic Ok I understand the original question now.
You don't have to be harsh.
Using FP utils it's definitely possible, I don't know where you got that idea from.
_.spread() is just the wrong tool, you need _.rest()

I have updated my solution, please take another look

Comment: Why you need your `rest` function if `partialRight` accept multiple arguments?

Comment: @jcubic We doing partial application from the right on the reduce function.
So what we end up with is a reduce function that is ready to take an iterable(which can be an array or whatever). In order to make the partial-ed reduce take multiple arguments, we have to compose it with rest. Which is opposite to spread.

Comment: I get it. I think this is exactly as my last code but you have this partialRight and I have standard curry because in my code I have function as first argument fn should go as first argument, lodash is broken because you can't run curry with lodash reduce. There is even a talk on YT about lodash being broken for FP, because it have all argument flipped, so lodash is not good example for any FP programming. Also my spread function is exactly the same as yours rest, but good to know that it have common name.